# Xpath Exclude p.class of a div

Tags: php, html, xpath

This is my HTML example:

```
<div id="Texte"> 
  <div class="pagination"> 
   ...  
  </div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>....</p>  
  <p class="Foot">...</p>
</div>
```

I want to use Xpath to get all content of my `<div id="Texte">` without the `<p class="foot">`.

I use this, but it's not ok, I have the class='Foot' in my result :

```
$crawler->filterXPath("//*[@id='Texte' and not(@class='Foot')]")->html();
```

Comment: I think you should use a good html parser

Comment: `html()` will create the HTML of the first node in the list. As long as you select `<div id="texte">` there, you'll have `<p class="Foot">` inside. The `filterXPath` method does not remove nodes here in case you thought. Most likely you're using the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score 0):

Almost.

```php
// correct
$crawler->filterXPath("//*[@id='Texte']/*[not(@class='Foot')]")->html();    

// yours, for comparison
$crawler->filterXPath("//*[@id='Texte' and not(@class='Foot')]")->html();
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have a problem with your answer. This give me just a p in the div with the class pagination. Have you an idea ?

Comment: @djoo I have only corrected the XPath. Maybe don't use `->html()` but something that returns *all* selected nodes? You need to look at the documentation of `filterXPath`.